# How do I set a default value for a "Money" type property in a Lightswitch 2013 entity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an entity with several properties with the "Money" data type.  I also have a Money property with a "computed" value that shows the sum of the other money type properties. However, a total will not display if any of the other fields are left with a null value. Is there way to make the default value set to "0"?  I am using c#.  Thank you.

Comment: Inside the money property's get accessor, you could check if any property returns null and then return zero else return computed sum

Comment: Hi Ben, I do not know where I would look to see Inside the Money property's get accessor.  Is it possible to elaborate? Thank you for your response, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you post some code for your money property? If its truly a property, it will have a set or get block inside it. Set is used to set the value, get to retrieve it.

Comment: If properties confuse you, i recommend doing some research on them.

Comment: Ben, Just so we are the same page, in Lightswitch a field or column is referred to as "property". When a property is added to the table (or in Lightswitch "entity") one chooses a data type out of a list of different data types that include Money, Phone, String, Number, ect. One can then add code for validation in either Visual Basic or C# which is what I determined when I first created the project.

Comment: Ah got it. Hmm. Obviously i dont know a lot about lighswitch. But my c# says look for part where you would actually set the value in the entity.

Comment: Here is a code:using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class Transaction
    {
        partial void TotalDue_Compute(ref decimal? result)
        {
            // Set result to the desired field value
            result = StandardServiceFee + EstoppleFee + StateSurcharge + MF2015 + MF2016; }
        partial void MF2016_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
        {
            // results.AddPropertyError("<Error-Message>");
           }
    }
}

Comment: is the TotalDue_Compute(decimal) the method that updates the sum of the other fields? Also, for future reference, that code might be something to include in your original post. Helps us understand the question

Comment: TotalDue is the "computed" field. I found that the solution is to "require" the fields in the Lightswitch. Pretty simple. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you can use "0.00M" to assign default value to a money type property.